# Adverse Drug Reaction Probability

Tags: probability

**I would like advice establishing how like to calculate a probability associated with an Adverse Drug Reaction.**

The assumptions are:
•   The period of research review is 1200 days. During the period of review the patient was prescribed Curalot, a medication manufactured by Bigg-Pharmer. It is prescribed control high blood pressure.
•   During the 1200 day review period the patient’s doctor prescribed Curalot on 12 occasions for 10 consecutive days.

o   During the 120 days Curalotal was prescribed, the patient reported 30 funny turns.
o   During the 1080 days when Curalot was not prescribed, the patient reported 10 funny turns.

Dr Quack, Bigg-Pharmer’s chief scientist, contends that the above findings are normal and a mere coincidence.

Q1. How can the patient prove Dr Quack is probably incorrect in his assumptions?
Q2. What is the probability of such skewed results being normal?
Assume Curalot has an instant beneficial effect which ceases immediate the patient stops taking the medication

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please avoid homework-type question, which will only lead your post to be ignored/downvoted. Instead, try to provide some context and show what you've tried so far, even if it wasn't fruitful.

Comment: You are expected to say Dr Quack is claiming the null hypothesis that says the chance of funny turns is independent of whether the drug is prescribed, then do a test to see if you can rule it out at some level.  It sure looks like there is a high correlation between prescription and funny turns.

Comment: I am sure there is a link fo some kind. It is not a Homework question. I have descibed a real life situation as if it was a homework question to simplify it. I have the real figures to prove it too which are different.
I found the average no of days between "funny turns" increased 14 times in frequency. But what I actually want to be able to do is calculate is how likely the results are ... like like less than 1% probablity.
The thing is I am 66 and have forgotten how to do it !!!

Comment: The medications are antuibiotics which have been linked to very subtle autoimmune and DNA Oxidative Stress problems.